# XSD Restrict values of multiple elements

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have a data source which has valid combinations of `product`, `index`, `type`.
Say valid combinations are

1. Product - ProductFoo
2. index - indexA
3. type - typeA

and

1. Product - ProductBar
2. index - indexB
3. type - typeB

The following would be a valid XML

```
<Entity name = "foo">
        <product>ProductFoo</product>
        <index>indexA</index>
        <type>typeA</type>
</Entity>
```

whereas the following isn't:

```
<Entity name = "bar">
        <product>ProductBar</product>
        <index>indexA</index>
        <type>typeA</type>
</Entity>
```

I have tried using choice, enumeration but may be am not using it right. Any thoughts if this could be done using a XSD?

Answer (score 0):

XSD 1.1's Conditional Type Assignment would allow you to vary the type of `Entity` based upon its `@name` attribute, and XSD 1.1's assertions could allow you to constrain the content of `product`.

However, consider instead changing your XML design if possible:

```
<foo>
  <ProductFoo/>
  <indexA/>
  <typeA/>
</foo>
```

Then your XML will be able to be modeled in XSD 1.0 simply.